# Variable as operator mssql

Tags: sql-server, variables, operators

I want to use a variable as operator like this;

```
DECLARE @OP VARCHAR(3) = 'AND' -- THIS COULD BE 'AND','OR'
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE Col1 = 1 @OP Col2 = 3
```

Obviously I cant use VARCHAR as this, the only other thing I can think of is SQL injection, but I wondered if there was an easier solution.

Please can you help.

Comment: You need `Dynamic SQL` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to execute dynamic SQL, but there is a way we can do this even without dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblName
WHERE
    (@OP = 'AND' AND Col1 = 1 AND Col2 = 3) OR
    (@OP = 'OR' AND (Col1 = 1 OR Col2 = 3));
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track apart from mssql is massive, and would create some doing to use this method, is there a way you can just declare a variable as an operator like; DECLARE @OP OPERATOR = AND

Comment: @Kiel No, there isn't.  You would need to execute a dynamic SQL string if you really have that requirement.

Comment: Well it is what it is, thanks for your help, I will try to put it in my code. Much appreciated..

Comment: If you need to do this a lot, then I recommend going the dynamic SQL route.  I have only had the need to use it sparingly in SQL Server, otherwise I would have also included that in my answer.

Comment: I think I can use it, just need to stare at my code for a while LOL.

Answer (score 1):

For completion, the dynamic SQL solution would be:

```
DECLARE @Op nvarchar(3) = N'AND';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM TblName WHERE Col1 = 1 ' + CASE WHEN @OP IN (N'AND',N'OR') THEN @OP END + N' Col2 = 3;';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

The `CASE` is there to avoid injection, as the value of `@Op` must be either `AND` or `OR` (otherwise the value of `@SQL` will result in `NULL` and nothing will be run).

If you need to parametrise the value of `Col1` and `Col2` then it would be:

```
DECLARE @OP nvarchar(3) = N'AND';
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

DECLARE @col1 int = 1, @col2 int =3;

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM TblName WHERE Col1 = @dCol1 ' + CASE WHEN @OP IN (N'AND',N'OR') THEN @OP END + N' Col2 = @dCol2;';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,N'@dCol1 int, @dCol2 int', @dCol1 = @Col1, @dCol2 = @Col2;
```

Comment: This works as well, I end up using without SQL injection, but both answers seem to work. Thanks..

Comment: Do you mean you took out the `CASE` expression @Kiel? If so, although it's an `nvarchar(3)`, personally, I'd still leave it there for "safety".